# PS4 pro is bricked after update - error "su-30746"

Tags: ps4

I just booted up my PS4 after maybe a month or two of inactivity from it, then noticed I had a pending software update. So then I proceeded to update and install the firmware that was downloading and once it had finished installing, it failed to restart back to the home screen.
After manually booting it back up I get an error `su-30746-0` which means "*Could not find file required for system software update*," according to Google.

Looking for a solution on the internet, I found that there is a simple fix for this which is to boot it up in Safe Mode by holding down the power button on the PS4 until two beeps can be heard.
Once I finally get it in Safe Mode I'm instructed to plug my controller in via a USB cable and press the PS button. However that part doesn't work. So it stays stuck in safe mode with the message "*Connect a DualShock 4 via USB and press the PS button*".

When I try to power on my controller it just blinks with a few lights then nothing, so basically I'm unable to access the Safe Mode options. I've tested the cables and found that they work, so I've ruled out that the PS4 will not communicate with the controllers in any way.

At this point I have no hope in getting back into my console, so I just thought that maybe someone here can give an alternative solution that I may not already know about. If anyone knows a solution to giving my PS4 its OS back, and getting around this, I'd really appreciate it <3.

Comment: You pressed the PS button while the it was already plugged into the console, right?

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to use the right *kind* of USB cable. It needed to be a data transfer capable USB cord. After using this kind of USB cord, it worked.